# Return string value from a database

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to get the `Patient`'s `Firstname` from a database but what I am getting when I run this piece of code is just a Linq expression string instead.

```
public static string GetPatientName(int bedNumber)
{
        var name = "";

        using (var data = new HospitalDBDataContext())
        {
             if (data.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
               data.Connection.Open();

             name = data.Patients.Where(x => x.BedNumber.Equals(bedNumber))
                                 .Select(x => x.Firstname).ToString();

            if (data.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
               data.Connection.Close();

            data.Dispose();
        }

        return name;
}
```

What is the way of making this Expression to return the actual value I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
name = data.Patients.Where(x => x.BedNumber.Equals(bedNumber))
                    .Select(x => x.Firstname).ToString();
```

Should be:

```
name = data.Patients.Where(x => x.BedNumber.Equals(bedNumber))
                    .Select(x => x.Firstname).FirstOrDefault();
```

You need to actually select `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()`. Right now you are casting the entire `IQueryable` statement into a string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `ToString` call that gives you the *Linq expression*

possible solutions. using FirstOrDefault to get first name.

```
name = data.Patients.Where(x => x.BedNumber.Equals(bedNumber)).Select(x => x.Firstname).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or use string.Join to get all the names in one string with separator like `,`(the first parameter passed to string.join).

```
name = string.Join(", " ,data.Patients.Where(x => x.BedNumber.Equals(bedNumber)).Select(x => x.Firstname));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Where` method returns an `Enumerable<T>` of results (patients), and the `Select` method returns a new `Enumerable<string>` with the `Firstname`s of each patient.

Instead of converting that `Enumerable<string>` to a string, you need to use a method like `Single` or `First` to get one object out of it.

(`Single` will throw an exception if there is more than one object in the `Enumerable<T>`, and `First` will throw an exception if there are no objects in the `Enumerable<T>`. Use `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault` if you want `null` instead of an exception in those cases.)